# Safe alternative way for INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

> Because the results of INSERT ... SELECT statements depend on the
>   ordering of rows from the SELECT and this order cannot always be
>   guaranteed, it is possible when logging INSERT ... SELECT ON DUPLICATE
>   KEY UPDATE statements for the master and the slave to diverge. Thus,
>   in MySQL 5.6.4 and later, INSERT ... SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   statements are flagged as **unsafe** for statement-based replication.

I wonder if there is a safe alternative way to perform this instruction and being safe at the same thing. For example. I want to create a betting game with the following schema:

```
Player       (player_id, player_name)
Player_Score (player_id, league_id, score)
Match        (match_id, league_id, team1_id, team2_id)
Player_Bet   (match_id, player_id, league_id, option)
```

Let say that I want to update score of all the player that has won the bet on specified match.

```
INSERT INTO Player_Score (player_id, league_id, score)
SELECT player_id, league_id, 1 FROM Player_Bet 
WHERE `option` = 1 AND match_id = 2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = score + 1
```

Comment: do the upsert (select and insert/update) in a serializable transaction.